# как в angularjs не загружать изображение

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как не загружать изображение если значение модели не строка?
Пока сделал проще, скрыл изображение, когда приходит вместо строки что то другое

```
 $scope.isString = function(item){
        return angular.isString(item);
    };

<img class="img-thumbnail black" ng-show="isString(item.image)" isImage width="280"
                                         ng-src="{{item.image}}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `ngIf`. В таком случае изображение действительно не будет загружаться. В случае с `ngShow` изображение просто не показывается, а запрос к несуществующему изображению все-таки отправляется на сервер.

Comment: да не там, связь с моделью стоит когда модель редактируется у нее есть изображение, когда жмёшь выбор изображения значение модели меняется на объект